# Nested Range-based for loop Not working in C++17

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17

I have made nested [Range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) program in C++17.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (int i : v) 
    {
        for (int a : i)
            std::cout << a << ' ';
    }
}
```

GCC genrated an error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:22: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
         for (int a : i)
```

So,

- Why does GCC generate an error for nested range based for loop?
- What is the scope of range based for loop?

Comment: Hint: it is all in the name. *Range* based for loop. **Range**.

Comment: @juanchopanza But second loop inside the first loop.

Comment: Please describe what exactly you think your code should do.  (1) it generates an error because your inner loop makes no sense, you are askong it to loop over an int.  (2) I have no idea what that question means.

Comment: `for (int a : i)` with `i` as an `int`. There is no range here to loop over.

Comment: @Yakk What does mean "error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope"?

Comment: You think that this is caused by the nested loop? That should be easy to check, by putting `int i = 0; for (int a : i) std::cout << a << ' ';` outside of the outer loop. I suspect you get the exact same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This problem has nothing to do with nested loops.**

The following code snippet is *nonsense* and the compiler ties itself into knots trying to understand it:

```
int main()  {
  std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  for (int i : v) {
    for (int a : i)
        std::cout << a << ' ';
  }
}
```

The error message thus is also *nonsense*. It is like feeding the compiler random characters, and the compiler coming back with "missing `;`".

In particular:

```
for (int i : v)
    for (int a : i)
```

The first line declares `i` as of type `int`. How could the second line, then, iterate over an `int`? `int` is not an array nor is it user-/library-defined.

Types that can be iterated over are arrays, and user/library defined types with a member `begin()`/`end()`, and such with a non-member free function `begin()`/`end()` in their namespace, whose `begin()`/`end()` return something iterator (or pointer) like.

`gcc` tried to treat it as an iterable object.  It isn't an array.  It doesn't have a member `begin()`.  It isn't defined in a namespace containing a non-member `begin()`.  This makes gcc give up at that point, and output a message that it could not find the non-member `begin()` in a nonsense location (as `int` has no point of definition).

This will generate the same error:

```
int i;
for( int a:i );
```

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
for (int a : i)
```

makes no sense. If you read the link on range-based loop you provided, you find that the inner loop would be equivalent to the following code,

```
{

    auto && __range = i ;
    auto __begin = begin(__range) ;
    auto __end = end(__range) ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {

        a = *__begin;
        std::cout << a << ' ';

    }

}
```

The `begin` and `end` functions are useful for vectors, maps, ranges etc. because they give iterators. They are also defined by the language for arrays, where they point to the beginning and past the end of the array, so the iterating syntax is the same. They are **not** defined for a plain `int` variable.

With this information the produced given by compiler is completely clear: it refers to the absence of `begin(i)` in the third line of the *transformed* code. That it is not declared in the scope where the inner loop appears (which is: the outer loop) is just an irrelevant detail at this point, it's not defined anywhere else in the program either.

Comment: I'm not sure the compiler error is that clear, if you don't know about ADL.